# How to add a column and fill it with values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table:

[image]

Using vba I need to add a column after UsedRange, add a header and fill cells after header with the same value until the last cell of UsedRange:

[image]

I have added new column and header:

```
Worksheets(ii).Cells(, Worksheets(ii).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column + 1).Value2 = "Column 4"
```

How can I fill values to the column (ignoring header)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way. I think `CurrentRegion` is more robust than `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)`.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
r.Cells(1, r.Columns.Count + 1).Value = "Column 4"
r.Cells(2, r.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1).Value = 2

End Sub
```